# linking css file in c++

Tags: css

i have a css file `style.css`
which has following code

```
.myClass
{
   color:red;
}
```

i want to use this css file to change the color of text in browser
following code of my program writes the text in browser

StringStream pageContent(sz, max_bytes);
pageContent.Write("Hello World!");//writes hello world in browser

when i do

```
pageContent.Write("<div style =\"color:red\"> hello world! <\div>");
```

text gets red but when i try to use css file using following code it doens't work

```
pageContent.Write("<link href=\"style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type =\"text/css\">");       

pageContent.Write(" <div id= \"myClass\"> Hello world! <\div>" );
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong or where should i place my file and how should i give the path to make it work?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with C++, it's just wrong usage of CSS selectors (see my answer). -- Re-tagged the question.

Comment: i want to use jquery, i have downloaded the jquery framework and saved it in a subfolder

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML: <div class="myClass">...</div>
CSS:  .myClass { color: red; }
```

or

```
HTML: <div id="myId">...</div>
CSS:  #myId { color: red; }
```

Research CSS selectors, there's enough literature about that on the web for me not to repeat it here. Basically `#someId` CSS selector for `id="someId"` HTML attribute and `.someClass` CSS selector for `class="someClass"` HTML attribute but there's a *lot* more to CSS selectors than just that.